# How to create a view that filters profiles based on current user's 'interested in' field value?

Tags: views, users

I am working on a small matrimonial application. I've installed the [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module and added a few fields like 'interested_in', 'gender', 'partner preference', etc to the users of my site.

I need to create a view that will list all profiles with same gender as logged in user's 'interested in' field.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

I used [MyModule_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) hook and added a join to the field table and the condition that matches the choice of logged in user and gender of users in db.

```
if ($view->name == 'profile_list') {
        $logged_in = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
        $pr = profile2_load_by_user($logged_in,'main');

        $join = new views_join();
        $join->table = 'field_data_field_gender';
        $join->field = 'entity_id';
        $join->left_table = 'profile';
        $join->left_field = 'pid';
        $join->type = 'inner';

        $query->add_relationship('field_data_field_gender', $join, 'profile');

        $view->query->add_where(0, db_and()->condition('field_data_field_gender.field_gender_value', $pr->field_looking_for['und']['0']['value'], '='));
    }
```